# Anchor tag opening page instead of downloading even with download attribute

Tags: javascript, html, download, anchor

So I have a simple program to download subtitles using opensubtitles api but the anchor tag which is supposed to download the srt file on clicking it is not working instead the file is opening as a webpage.

Here's the relevant part:

```
fetch(url_sub_download,options)
                    .then(response => response.json())
                    .then(response => {
                        console.log(response);
                        console.log(i,response.link);

                        const sub_section=document.querySelector(".subtitle_section");
                        sub_section.innerHTML+=`<div class="sub${i}"> 
                        <h3>Subtitle ${i}</h3>
                        <a href="${response.link}" download="Subtitle ${i}"><i class="fa-solid fa-download"></i></a>
                        </div>`;
                    })
                    .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

Also here's the link to github repo:

[text](https://github.com/MobasshirAjaz/Subtle)

And here's the link to website hosted using github:

[text](https://mobasshirajaz.github.io/Subtle/)

To reproduce the problem, just go the above website, search any movie,click on any of the generated card, click the download button for any of the generated subtitle links.

As I have only implemented the mobile view it will be better to change the view to mobile in dev tools.

I expected the anchor tag to download subtitle file, but instead it opens the file as a webpage.

Comment: Note that the "download" attribute only works for same-origin URLs. Also, there's no guarantee what the browser will do in response. On the other hand, if your server sends a `Content-Disposition: attachment` header, it's more likely to work. That is, if the file to be downloaded is actually *on* your server. If it's on a different domain, it won't work and you can't control that from the browser.

Comment: So nothing I can do from my side? The opensubtitles api is being used in many projects though. So maybe there's some issue from my side.

Comment: Well, to repeat: if the URL in the `<a>` tag is **your** domain, then it *should* work, though different browsers on different platforms *might* do quirky things. If it is your own domain, then setting `Content-Disposition` is better anyway. If the URL is a **different** domain than your own, you cannot control it: the "download" attribute in the `<a>` tag will be ignored.